# Deleting specific keys from an array of object

Tags: javascript

```
var arrayObjects = [{key1:'value',key2:'value2'},{'key1:'value',key2:'value2}]

for(i = 0; i <arrayObjects.length; i++) {
    for (key in arrayObjects[i]) {
          delete key1; // Delete the key
          delete arrayObjects[i]['key1'] // Delete the Key's Value

    }

}
```

I get a error message `'cannot delete property of null'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `delete key1;`, just do:

```
for(i = 0; i <arrayObjects.length; i++) {
    delete arrayObjects[i]['key1'] // Delete the Key
}
```

If you only want to delete `key1` from each array entry.